# MongoDB - How to get specified values of an array in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Here is the document

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('61a4262a53ddaa8b93374613'),
  'userid': 'renyi',
  'data1': [{'a': 1}, 1, 2, 3],
  'data2': [{'c': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'c': 2}],
  'data': {'0': {'a': 1}}
}
```

With this

```py
coll.find_one({'userid':'renyi','data2.c':1},{'_id':0,"data2.$":1})
```

I can get

```
{'data2': [{'c': 1}]}
```

But how to get

```
{'data2': [{'c': 1},{'c': 2}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$filter` to filter the element within the array in projection.

```
db.collection.find({
  "userid": "renyi",
  "data2.c": {
    $in: [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "data2": {
    $filter: {
      input: "$data2",
      cond: {
        $in: [
          "$$this.c",
          [
            1,
            2
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eWwyvlgTdjZ)